# For loops to take specific values only in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have a MATLAB program which uses two `for` loops to iterate up to 5 times. However, I want MATLAB to use only `(1 1), (2 2), (3 3)` and so on.

Here is the program:

```
syms l
a = [0 1 0 0 1 0;1 1 1 0 1 1;1 0 0 0 1 1;1 1 1 0 0 1;0 1 1 0 1 1];
n = [2 1;1 1;1 1;1 1;2 1];

for l = 1:5 
    for i = 1:5
        j = n(l,1);

        if a(i,j) == 0
           a(i,j:end) = circshift(a(i,j:end),[n(l,2) n(l,2)]);

           for j = n(l,1):n(l,1)+n(l,2)
               a(i,n(l,1)) = 1;
           end

        else 
           a(i,j:end) = circshift(a(i,j:end),[n(l,2) n(l,2)]);

           for j = n(l,1):n(l,1)+n(l,2)
               a(i,n(l,1)) = 0;
           end
        end

    break;
    end 

    break;
end
```

I want MATLAB my program to work like this:

```
first l = 1 and i = 1;
second l = 2 and i = 2;
third l = 3 and i = 3;
fourth l = 4 and i = 4;
```

and so on...

Comment: What does C++ have to do with this?

Comment: so that it reaches more people.. and obviously C++ can also do this.. I just need a logic to do this.

Comment: @user3476378 You are misusing the c++ tag! SO tagging doesn't work this way. Ask for [tag:algorithm] then ...

Comment: Lots of questions have concepts that apply to more than one language. That doesn't mean the tags are there to just stick on  in order for more people to see it. Each language will probably do it a bit differently for starters.

Comment: Why don't you just make `l` and `i` the same variable ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Paul .. I want like this, after i = 1, then exit the loop and then take l = 2 and i = 2, and so on..

Comment: @user3476378: So, use a single loop: `for ii = 1:N, l=i; [rest of code here]; end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RodyOldenhuis basically answered your question, and I'm flattered he hasn't made this into an actual answer!

Simply take your code and change the inner `for` loop index so that it matches the outer loop index.  In other words, do this:

```
syms l %// Why are you doing this?
a = [0 1 0 0 1 0;1 1 1 0 1 1;1 0 0 0 1 1;1 1 1 0 0 1;0 1 1 0 1 1];
n = [2 1;1 1;1 1;1 1;2 1];

for l = 1:5 
    i = l; %// Change here - Remove second for loop
    %// ... [rest of your code here]
    %// Get rid of the break in this loop
    end 
    %// Removed break here too
end
```